# How do I load all of the .py files I have cloned from a Github repo in Colab?

Tags: python, github, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

I have cloned a GitHub repository and it has successfully imported all of the .py files I need on the left. I have set up a for loop that takes all of the .py files and saves them into an array. Now I want to loop through and run them all so that I can use their classes and functions without actually having to repaste their code into colab.

[Example of list of .py files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrHX5.png)

I thought the below method would work:

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeBji.png)

But as shown, it says there is no such file or directory. Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: You want to run them all? Wouldn't importing be a better way to have access to the classes and functions?

Comment: Sorry I'm really really new to using GitHub so I'm not too sure what is the norm. How would I be able to import all of the classes and functions? I had tried that originally after cloning the repo using the typical "import" method on colab but it didn't seem to be working for me. Wasn't sure if I had to run the .py files first before I could then import classes and functions from those files.

Comment: EDIT: Managed it, the problem I was having was that I wasn't in the correct directory when trying to import the classes and functions I needed.

Comment: Importing is not about git, but about Python itself. Executing all the files in the way you are doing you will have access to the function and classes, but all of the function calls inside a ```if __name__ == "__main__"``` block would be executed as well, if you want just to gain access to the functions, it is a better practice to import the module. Now that you are on the right directory, try importing them instead of executing, the result should be the same, but as I said, best practices

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks @LuísOtávio